# What is the best approach for large numbers of concurrent mappings

Tags: ignite

I am trying to work out what the best approach would be for the following problem?

**Conditions**:

1. You have a river of data flowing at a varying rate into a cache, the cache holds the last **N** minuets of data.
2. The river of data has to be analyzed as fast as possible
3. You have over 10,000 different map reduce functions that has to aggregate into at least 1,000,000 buckets

**Question**:
Is it a good idea to spin up 10k continuous mappers or is there a better way?

Thank you for assistance

Answer (score 0):

This is also discussed on Apache Ignite user forum: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/What-is-the-best-approach-for-large-number-of-concurrent-mappings-td11445.html